# How to automatically accept the printer's status window?

Tags: windows, api, winapi

How to automatically accept the printer's status window?
The CAD API displays the following print window.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWP4z.png)
I want to automatically accept and print.
Does the Windows API have such a feature?
Could you please help me how to use it?
Thank you.

Comment: What is your question? How printing is done is completely controlled by the program. There is no need to show any dialog for this job. Also the print dialog routines have a feature to tell them to show no UI and just return a printer DC... Please make your question more precise and show us code or a minimal sample.

Comment: I've done something similar using [FindWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx) to find the printer dialog by it's title, and then walking its child windows, asking each for it's text using [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) with the WM_GETTEXT message.  When you find a window with window-class "button" and the text "print", you simulate a mouse-click on it using SendMessage and WM_LBUTTONDOWN/WM_LBUTTONUP messages.  It's dirty, but it has worked since Windows 3.1

Comment: I vote for @lockcmpxchg8b 's idea. I wrote something similar that waits for Winamp to show up and presses the Play button. Yup, I'm too lazy to click the Play button, I wrote a code to do it for me.